# Copy-Paste the values of a specific column

Tags: excel

I'm trying to copy-paste a specific column in a given range to my current column. Let's say: I want to get the column that has the header named "AGGR" in range of A:L to the current cell I selected.

| Column A | Column B | Column C | AGGR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Value1 | Value2 | Value3 | Value4 |
| Value1 | Value2 | Value3 | Value4 |

| ColumnD | ColumnE | ColumnF |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Value1 | Value2 | Value3 |
| Value1 | Value2 | Value3 |

So here I want to copy paste the column that has the header named "AGGR" right next to Column F

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This calls for an `INDEX/MATCH` formula, like this one:

```
=INDEX(A2:D2,1,MATCH("AGGR",A$1:D$1,0))
```

It means the following:

- In the first row ("A$1:D$1"), find "AGGR" using an exact match (0). The result will always be 4.
- In the second row, take the first row (which is the row itself) and take the fourth column.

You must understand that "A2:D2" is a relative reference, meaning that it will change to "A3:D3" and further when you drag to next lines. However the row where to search for "AGGR" will be fix, using the absolute reference "$1".

Hereby a screenshot:

[image]